# Is the image of a tensor product equal to the tensor product of the images?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, homological-algebra, tensor-products

Let $S$ be a commutative ring with unity, and let $A,B,A',B'$ be $S$-modules. If $\phi:A\rightarrow A'$ and $\psi:B\rightarrow B'$ are $S$-module homomorphisms, is it true that

$$\operatorname{im}(\phi\otimes\psi)=\operatorname{im}(\phi)\otimes_S \operatorname{im} (\psi)?$$

Comment: There is also an explanation in Keith Conrad's notes on tensor products (Example 2.14)-http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/linmultialg/tensorprod2.pdf

Answer (score 17, accepted):

No, because the map $im(\phi)\otimes_S im(\psi) \to A'\otimes_S B'$ may
not be injective.

E.g. consider the case $S = \mathbb Z$, $A = A' = B =\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z,$ $B' = \mathbb Q/\mathbb Z$, $\phi = id_A$, and $\psi: \mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z \hookrightarrow \mathbb Q/\mathbb Z$ is the unique injection.

Then the map $A \otimes_S B \to im(\phi) \otimes_S im(\psi)$ is an isomorphism, while the map $\phi \otimes_S \psi$ is the zero map, since $A'\otimes_S B' = 0$.

---

More generally, if you restrict to the case when $\phi$ is the identity, and $\psi$ is injective, you
are asking whether the injection $\psi: B \hookrightarrow B'$ induces an injection $A\otimes_S B \hookrightarrow A \otimes_S B'$.  The answer is no in general because tensoring is not left exact.  (The preceding example is one illustration of this.)

Comment: Thanks a lot for great answer. I don't quite see what the unique injection $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ is though...could you please tell me? And what if all the modules $A,A',B,B'$ are free $S$- modules (even finitely generated), do we then have $$\operatorname{im}(\phi\otimes\psi)=\operatorname{im}(\phi)\otimes_{S}\operatorname{im}(\psi)?$$

Comment: $\psi : A \rightarrow \psi(A)$ and $\phi: B \rightarrow \phi(B)$ are surjective. Thus $\psi\otimes 1_B:A \otimes B \rightarrow \psi(A) \otimes B$ and $1_{\psi(A)} \otimes \phi : \psi(A) \otimes B \rightarrow \psi(A) \otimes \phi(B)$ are surjective. Thus $\psi \otimes \phi = (1_{\psi(A)} \otimes g) \circ (\psi \otimes 1_B)$ is surjective. What am i missing?

Comment: Thus $im(\psi \otimes \phi) = \psi(A) \otimes \phi(B)=im(\psi) \otimes im(\phi)$.

Comment: @Manos: Dear Manos, The map from the tensor product of the images to the image of the tensor product is surjective, but not injective in general (e.g. as in the example I give).  Regards,

Comment: @BartPatzer: Dear Bart, The group $\mathbb Q/Z$ has a unique subgroup of order two; let $\psi$ be the unique isomorphism of $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$ with this subgroup.  Regards,

Comment: @MattE: Dear Matt, thanks for your answer. I understand the argument that you gave in your answer. What i can't see, is where i am wrong in my argument in my comment.

Comment: @Manos: Dear Manos, You are trying to identify $\phi(A)\otimes \phi(B)$ with its image in $A'\otimes B'$, which is not possible in general since tensor products are not left-exact: there is a surjection from the first to the second, but it is not injective in general.  Regards,

Comment: What should be the case for linear maps between linear spaces?

Comment: @Wfpiggie For linear maps between linear spaces they are equal. This follows (and it is equivalent) from the property that the rank of Kronecker product of two matrices (over an arbitrary field) equals the product of ranks. (Btw, this property deserves a proof as long as many classical textbooks in linear algebra, e.g. Horn & Johnson, give proofs only for real matrices via SVD.)